# Swift error when trying to assign: newString = oldString.removeLast(Int)

Tags: swift, string

I'm not seeing something very basic w/assigning the results of Swift string methods (Swift 4, Xcode 9.1 playground). 
anyString.removeLast(X) works fine on its own, modifying anyString with X less characters at the end, but if I try to assign the result to a declared variable, like: newString = anyString.removeLast(X), I get an error. Here are examples with results or fails in comments:

```
var address = "St. James St."
var searchedFor = "St."
var replaceWith = "Street"
var standardAddress = ""
if address.hasSuffix(searchedFor) {
    address.removeLast(searchedFor.count)
    standardAddress = address + replaceWith
}
print(standardAddress)
// prints: St. James Street
```

But this fails:

```
var address = "St. James St."
var searchedFor = "St."
var replaceWith = "Street"
var standardAddress = ""
if address.hasSuffix(searchedFor) {
    standardAddress = address.removeLast(searchedFor.count) + replaceWith
    // error: type 'inout String' does not conform to protocol 'BidirectionalCollection' standardAddress = address.removeLast(searchedFor.count) + replaceWith
}
print(standardAddress)
```

And this fails too, with a different Xcode playground error:

```
var address = "St. James St."
var searchedFor = "St."
var replaceWith = "Street"
var standardAddress = ""
if address.hasSuffix(searchedFor) {
    standardAddress = address.removeLast(searchedFor.count)
    // error: cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String' standardAddress = address.removeLast(searchedFor.count)
}
print(standardAddress)
```

Thanks for helping me understand differences above.

Comment: Lookup the documentation: `removeLast(count:)` has no return value. It modifies its receiver.

Comment: Thanks. I had just assumed it would be modified and then the resultant mod could be assigned to the left side of an equal, but This needs to execute on a stand alone line before the change can be assigned in another expression?